# how can we run drag and drop codes with the help of html, css and a bit of javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Web Page</title>
         <script>
            function dragstart(ev){
               ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
            }
            function dragfinish(ev){
             ev.preventDefault();   
            }
            function dropstart(ev){
                var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
                ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
                ev.preventDefault();
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p text-style="center"> I started to work on drag and drop</p>
<div style="width:400px;height:380px; border:2px; border-style:solid;"   id="div1" ondrop="dropstrat(event)" ondragover="dragfinish(event)"></div>  
<div style="height:300></div>
    <img id="pic1  src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTAqB_HEXzRtgLQiHn71I1-ph0cAhoiBXkMwA&usqp=CAU" width="355" height="355" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragstart(event)">
    </body>
```

I tried this code but have no idea what is wrong with it?
can anyone help  me!
I wonder whether the problems roots in my web browser, upper case or lowercase, or I don't know maybe a semicolon can make problem? the thing is I can drag an element in my web page, but I cannot drop in in the div that I defined, I guess all went well except the time I wrote script.

Comment: What *is* wrong with it? What do you expect to happen? What happens instead? Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: `text-style="center"` is an invalid attribute

Comment: `style="height:300` is missing `"`

Comment: Don't use `style` on `on*` attributes. CSS and JS should be in one place only, and those are their respective tags or files.

Comment: `<script>` should be ideally right before the closing `</body>` tag, not in `<head>`

Comment: I can drag my element but I cannot drop it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your

```
ondrop="dropstrat(event)"
```

**instead of**

```
ondrop="dropstart(event)"
```

Comment: So, if it's a typo the question can be closed as such

Answer (score 0):

A lot of typos, missing quote etc

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>My Web Page</title>
  <script>
    function dragstart(ev) {
      ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);
    }

    function dragfinish(ev) {
      ev.preventDefault();
    }

    function dropstart(ev) {
      var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
      ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
      ev.preventDefault();
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <p text-style="center"> I started to work on drag and drop</p>
  <div style="width:400px;height:380px; border:2px; border-style:solid;" id="div1" ondrop="dropstart(event)" ondragover="dragfinish(event)"></div>
  <div style="height:300"></div>
  <img id=" pic1" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTAqB_HEXzRtgLQiHn71I1-ph0cAhoiBXkMwA&usqp=CAU" width="355" height="355" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragstart(event)" />
</body>
```

Comment: oh thank you a zillion time. I TRY TO BE ACCURATE.